# How to work PHP header in _blank mode

Tags: php, html

I want to use PHP header in _blank mode but it is not working; Here is my code.

```
<?php
$g = $_POST['G'];
    if($g) {
    header("Location: http://www.softbazz.com/", "_blank");

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>



<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<input type="submit" name="G" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My point is can this code do my job.

```
header("Location: http://www.softbazz.com/", "_blank");
```

Please help me. Thank You.
If you need demo please go to this [site](http://test.softbazz.com/).

Comment: @Jack: But sir there is not answar

Comment: @Softbazz Jack gave you the answer, actually.

Comment: PHP is **serverside** Browser (TAB) is **clientside** so you can't use header to open a new tab!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine php and js to get the answer.This will open a new tab if $g is true .Works 100%, tested in my localhost

```
    <?php

            $g = $_POST['G'];
            if($g) 
           {
             echo "<script>window.open(\"http://www.softbazz.com/\", '_blank');</script>";
           }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to redirect the page n a new window. But you cannot do it. `header()` will redirect in the current window.

But JavaScript might come in handy for this case.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('http://www.example.com');</script>
```

Comment: So there is no solution in PHP

Comment: You cannot do it with the server side language. you have to use JS.

Comment: the idea with the `window.open` is good but you should be carefull where you put it. If you put it on the page and it opens itself in a new window you got some trouble with an infinite-loop there.

Comment: @Fawzan: Sir I have PHP codes to run in fwrite function so I need that in PHP

Comment: If you can elaborate your question a little bit clear, we may be able to help you. :)

Comment: @Fawzan: I make something like wordpress preview options, but wordpress have auto saving system but in here I am trying to make that in my way, I thing that I just set a default page for fwrite and when I click preview then the page will write and it will open in new window, thats it

Comment: Hope you got the answer from @Unni

Answer (score 0):

In PHP it is possible you need to complete this action by javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('http://www.softbazz.com/',width=700,height=500, resizable=1, left=0, top=0');</script>
```